# Bitcoin: transaction completed, bitcoins never arrived

Tags: bitcoind, synchronization

I'm currently mining some bitcoins during normal computer use. I am using windows. The wallet is Bitcoin, as a miner I am using GUIMiner and pooled mining.

I am happy with the way everything works, however, I wanted to move my wallet to another location, so that I had access to it everywhere. I rented a virtual linux machine running Ubuntu 12.04, then installed bitcoind. I created an account and a new address.

For testing purposes, I transferred 1 BCCent to the new address. I was watching the sending wallet waiting for transfer confirmations, that never came. However, I remembered that the first time starting a wallet it takes quite a lot of time to synch to the network completely, so I went to sleep.

In the morning, the transaction was done and was affirmed by a lot of sources. I confidently checked my target wallet, and found that there were no bitcoins on the address and the account.

Checking the wallet for the transaction using

```
bitcoind gettransaction <the used txid>
```

gives the message

```
error: {"code":-5,"message":"Invalid or non-wallet transaction id"}
```

I am not sure how this could happen. I've double-checked the target address, and it matches.

Does anyone have an idea how such a thing can happen?

Comment: Check to make sure that your blockchain is fully up to date. I can't remember the command offhand, but you want to make sure of that. Maybe it's still syncing or got stuck somehow.

Comment: Have you tried restarting bitcoind with the -rescan option?

Comment: @ColinDean You were and are right. Somehow, not all blocks have been synchronized. If you formulate it as an answer (the option is, as Nick ODell said, -rescan), I'll accept it.

Comment: You should check it again after 3 hours.